# Parse cloud code deploy take time to propogate

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

OK. So I decided to use Parse as my development server and to use cloud code specifically to expose all my API..

I found that every time I deploy my cloud code and call my cloud function I intermittently get the old version of the function instead of the new one. 
This behavior leads me to believe that it takes time for my new cloud code to propagate to all servers.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue?
Can this be mitigated?

Comment: Don't think I've seen that happen before while testing

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it can take a few seconds, sometimes up to a minute for the changes to propagate throughout the system. That is expected behavior when working with Cloud Code.

An alternative would be to use [Webhooks](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-advanced-cloud-code-webhooks), which basically maps a Cloud Code function or a save/delete hook to a URL on a server you control. It also has the benefit of giving you more runtime (30 seconds vs. 15 seconds for functions) for the functions compared to running it directly on Parse.